# Unable to generate Java files from wsdl using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to generate a Java file using wsimport from wsdl, but I am getting the following exception since it is using soap12.

Is there a way to generate correct files using wsimport?

I was able to import using soapUI, but I don't think so it is proper, because I don't see any annotation in this.
wsdl -> https://tatapvuat.tmibasl.in/VISoFICService/VisofClaimService.svc?wsdl

> [WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "EndpointReference" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing")
>     line 1 of https://tatapvuat.tmibasl.in/VISoFICService/VisofClaimService.svc?wsdl
>
> [WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'VisofClaimService.svc?xsd=xsd0', because 'https' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
>     line 1 of https://tatapvuat.tmibasl.in/VISoFICService/VisofClaimService.svc?wsdl#types?schema1
>
> [WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "WSHttpBinding_IVisofClaimService": it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
>   You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
>     line 1 of https://tatapvuat.tmibasl.in/VISoFICService/VisofClaimService.svc?wsdl
>
> [WARNING] Service "VisofClaimService" does not contain any usable ports. try running wsimport with -extension switch.
>     line 1 of https://tatapvuat.tmibasl.in/VISoFICService/VisofClaimService.svc?wsdl

Comment: Re *"I need urgent help on this"*: [No, no, no, no, NO, NO, NO!!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuRlLjd3700&t=393).